# error collection in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I am trying to change the css of a textbox based on an error on the page. Say to turn the background of the textbox red. I want to do this through the base page so that each codebehind that inherits this base page will perform this function. I am trying to do this in the OnLoad event

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    //code here
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

How do I access the error collection in the base page something like this...

```
for each(var error in Page.Errors)
{
    TextBox textBox = error.textboxInError;
    textBox.Background - Color = "Red";
}
```

To be more specific I want to trigger on page validation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using web forms validators, you could do something like this:

```
// Get a collection of all validators to check, sort of like this
var allValidators = new[] { validator1, validator2, validator3 };

foreach (var validator in allValidators)
{
    validator.Validate();
    var ctrl = (WebControl)Page.FindControl(validator.ControlToValidate);
    ctrl.BackColor = validator.IsValid ? Colors.Red : Colors.White;
}
```

**Update**

Apparently, the `Page` object has a collection of validators.  See [Page.Validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.validators.aspx).  Here's some revised code using that:

```
foreach (var validator in Page.Validators)
{
    validator.Validate();
    var ctrl = (WebControl)Page.FindControl(validator.ControlToValidate);
    ctrl.BackColor = validator.IsValid ? Colors.Red : Colors.White;
}
```

Comment: I understand this for sure and that was my plan, I am wondering how to get the collection of all the errors that have happened on the page. Ie the allValidators you have used.

Comment: See my update; there's a Page property that enumerates the validators.

Comment: validator.Validate()... how is this done? It does not exist as far as I can tell. Thanks again. This works for Page but not for specific errors as far as I can tell. This is what I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

[Check This tutorial Out](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages). It will help you create a Custom Error Page, and trap the error at either Application, Page or Web.Config level.